# scoring mechanism used in given ElasticSearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I just want to know the scoring mechanism(similarity) used in the given index.For example, if I have a index called test_es, then I want to know which scoring mechanism is used in test_es index.
Also, I wanted to know by default in elasticsearch 8.3 which scoring mechanism is used.

My usecase is I have a field called subjects which is a list. This field will be having multiple values.
For example one doc has ['subject one', 'subject two', 'subject three'], another doc has ['one test', 'one example', 'two'] in field name. So when I search for **subject one** in field **name**, I should get the first document first since it is most relevant, but I was getting the second doc first, even though I am sorting the result by _score
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a very general question, if you don't have any extra mechanism Elasticsearch results are by default scored according to BM25 as explained in the [similarity module of Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html)

You can also take a look at other available [similarity systems in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#_available_similarities)

Comment: thank you. i have updated my use case in the above question. can you pls check

Comment: @sudheesh, there is no easy way to handle your requirements, please read more about how tf-idf and its enhanced version BM25 works, Also please upvote and accept answer as it answer your first question, please ask a follow up question with more information(after understanding BM25 algo)